# С++ Хранение, вывод и парсинг даты и времени в формате yyyyMMdd-HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn

Tags: c++, timestamp, c++20, std-chrono

Столкнулся с проблемой хранения даты и времени, а также считыванием и выводом по шаблону, а именно: 
`yyyyMMdd-HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn` (пример: 20211215-06:36:01.571670316).

**ВАРИАНТ 1**

Мне необходимо хранить дату вплоть до наносекунд, я нашел некоторые примеры для `std::chrono::nanoseconds`, из написанного понял что это период `std::chrono::duration` с 1970, и я могу путем преобразований получить дни, часы, минуты, секунды и т.д. вплоть до наносекунд (брал [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677964/print-current-system-time-in-nanoseconds-using-c-chrono)):

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
    typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio_multiply<std::chrono::hours::period, std::ratio<8>>::type> Days; // UTC: +8:00
    Days days = std::chrono::duration_cast<Days>(duration);
    duration -= days;
    auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(duration);
    duration -= hours;
    auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(duration);
    duration -= minutes;
    auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration);
    duration -= seconds;
    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration);
    duration -= milliseconds;
    auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);
    duration -= microseconds;
    auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration);
    std::cout << hours.count() << ":"
    << minutes.count() << ":"
    << seconds.count() << "."
    << milliseconds.count()
    << microseconds.count()
    << nanoseconds.count() << std::endl;
```

**Вопрос 1.1**: Каким образом хранимые в этом формате данные можно представить в виде `std::string` или `char*` в соответствии с шаблоном дата время: `yyyyMMdd-HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn` ?

**Вопрос 1.2**: Каким образом, дату полученную в рамках шаблона в строковом виде `std::string` или `char*` можно преобразовать/распарсить в тот же `std::chrono::duration` для дальнейшего хранения и вывода в строковом формате.

**Вопрос 1.3**: Если `std::chrono::duration` не подходит для хранения необходимой информации, в каком виде ее можно было бы хранить для удобного и быстрого использования (парсинг, вывод)?

---

**ВАРИАНТ 2**

Также пробовал использовать следующий подход (брал [здесь](https://gist.github.com/dtoma/cc3d5b2dd4c03a25886adededcc1e3b9)), дата и время берутся из одного источника `std::chrono::time_point`, наносекунды путем дополнительного преобразования в `std::chrono::duration`:

```
std::chrono::time_point now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
auto tm = *std::gmtime(&time);

auto epoch = now.time_since_epoch();
auto ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(epoch).count() % 1000000000;

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y%m%d-%T.");
auto str = oss.str();

std::cout << str << ns ;
```

Вывод: `20220110-04:00:25.576973219`.

В целом все в порядке, для хранения используется один тип данных `std::chrono::time_point`, однако мне не нравятся доп. преобразования наносекунд `std::chrono::duration` а также полное преобразование по шаблону из `std::ostringstream`.

**Вопрос 2.1**: Я сомневаюсь в правильности вышеописанного подхода - на сколько это "рабочая схема" с несколькими преобразованиями и есть ли варианты проще для получения результата сразу в `std::string` или `char*`?

**Вопрос 2.2**: Как правильно получить `std::chrono::time_point` по шаблону из `std::string` или `char*`?

с++20 `std::format` к сожалению не работает в gcc.

**Дополнительная информация:**

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.3
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
```

Хотя Clion пишет что cmake 3.21.1

Comment: почитал все это. std::format можно подключить отдельно - https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt  или, закрыв рты анонимным минусаторам, просто использоваться sprintf, тем более, что в данном случае размер строки будет фиксированный. А ещё, я бы все это завернул в один класс, который внутри спрячет всю логику и наносекунды хранить просто в беззнаковом целом.

Comment: @KoVadim Я в целом не против обертки, но было бы куда сподручнее пара методов print & parse с одним входным и одним выходным параметром. Потому и спрашиваю какие есть современные варианты хранения, пока что нашел именно эти. Изначально предполагал, что std::chrono умеет всё из коробки, но либо я не понимаю/не нашел, либо действительно нужно "изловчиться". 
На счет std::format - большое спасибо, но держусь формата - меньше внешних либ.

Comment: я сильно не уверен, что такое есть из коробки. Поэтому, я бы делал класс, внутрь наверно все таки sprintf и поехали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> с++20 std::format к сожалению не работает в gcc.

Стало быть придётся использовать C++11 (опуская std и std::chrono).

> ...из написанного понял что это период std::chrono::duration с 1970,...

Это не так, это просто интервал времени, как минимум, не более ±292 лет. Но Вы можете условиться, что он от 1 января 1970 и это упростит код.

> Вопрос 1.1

1. Получаем значение `time_t` и остаток наносекунд с помощью `lldiv(dur_ns.clock(), 1000000000LL)` и преобразования типа;
2. Получаем `tm` с помощью `gmtime()`;
3. Получаем строку с помощью, либо `ss << put_time(&tmb, "%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.") << setfill('0') << setw(9) << lldres.rem`, либо `strftime()`, либо `snprintf()`.

> Вопрос 1.2

1. Получаем `tm` и `double` с помощью, либо `ss >> get_time(&tmb, "%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S") >> dfs`, либо `strptime()` (POSIX) и `strtoll()`, либо `snprintf()`;
2. Получаем `time_t` с помощью `mktime()`;
3. Получаем `nanoseconds(time*1000000000LL + llns)`.

> ВАРИАНТ 2
> Также пробовал использовать следующий подход (брал здесь)

**В нём две ошибки**:

- `system_clock::to_time_t()` можно применить к `time_point< high_resolution_clock>` только в случае совпадения `system_clock` и `high_resolution_clock`, а это не всегда так, по стандарту: они различаются в двух случаях из трёх, например, у clang++;
- При выводе наносекунд старшие нули исчезают.

И вообще, у этого варианта есть несколько подводных камней:

- `high_resolution_clock` может быть монотонным (is_steady), т.е. его вообще преобразовать в нормальное время не получится;
- `system_clock` может иметь разрешение хуже наносекунд (формально и для `high_resolution_clock` нет гарантий за наносекунды);
- Таким образом, для строго соблюдения стандарта и переносимости следует использовать `time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>`, но писанины и работы оптимизатору будет немного больше.

> Вопрос 2.1

Есть вариант одновременного получения значения `time_t` и остатка наносекунд с помощью `lldiv(tpns.time_since_epoch().count(), 1000000000LL)` и преобразования типа.

> Если std::chrono::duration не подходит для хранения необходимой информации, в каком виде ее можно было бы хранить для удобного и быстрого использования (парсинг, вывод)?

`duration`, как и `time_point`, не то, что бы совсем не подходят, но использование `timespec` (C++17, C11, POSIX) для хранения и ввода/вывода/регистрации должно быть, и шустрее, и проще, и надёжнее.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Воспользовался советом работать с timespec, сделал парсинг и вывод, работает хорошо.